# Django recommendation for flow

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, github

I am starting my first project >> DJango.
I try to think about what process I need to do to work properly.

1. Install a Docker on my PC or open a VM?
2. Install the Django work environment.
   3.Replace to postgres database.
3. How often should I use git version control, meaning when do you upload your changes? (By number of changes or by each X time?)
4. Deploy the APP to AWS / heroku / digital ocean (what do you recommend?)
   [image]

Comment: You should be looking at Python virtual environments for day-to-day development work.  A full isolation environment like Docker is more than you need, and it can be pretty inconvenient to work with (you wind up working around many of its features to make it act like a local development environment; a Python virtual environment _is_ a local development environment).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your experience with Python and web development on the whole? I don't feel like it's entirely necessary for you to do all of or any of these thing if you aren't particularly familiar with one of those skill sets. Additionally, what exactly are you trying to build?

My recommendations for you can/might vary wildly depending on what you're hoping to make with Django.

So I think some more context may be helpful before it makes sense for anyone to provide some suggestions for what you should be setting up to work on Django apps.

Answer (score 1):

i have been using cookie cutter boilerplate for the Django projects
i will definitely refer you to use this link you can directly generate the scalable and deploy able projcect using this link

pip install cookiecutter

cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

or checkout more at https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django